# Self invocation of interactive shell through Python3 with bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I am using python3 and [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to spawn a process of `bash` and invoking the Python3 interpreter again through the standard interpreter.

`bash -i` states:

> ```
>   -s        If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after
>             option processing, then commands are read from the standard
>             input.  This option allows the positional parameters to be
>             set when invoking an interactive shell.
> ```

This is a minimized example but it mainly bakes down to the following code:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-s"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=sys.stderr, stdout=sys.stdout)

p.stdin.write(b"python3\n")
p.stdin.flush()

print("Done")
```

The output is simply "Done". Any suggestions how I need to handle the stdin pipes in order to let the interactive shell pop up inside the newly executed python3 interpreter?

**Actual output**

```bash
% python3 test.py 
Done
```

**Expected output:**

```bash
% python3 test.py
Python 3.10.8 (main, Oct 13 2022, 10:17:43) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Your inner invocation of Python isn't going to behave like a normal interactive session (so no welcome message, no prompts) because it can tell that its input is not connected to a terminal; try running it with `python3 -i`.  You'll also need to forward input to the process, perhaps something like `while not p.poll(): p.stdin.write(sys.stdin.readline())`.

Comment: Thanks jasonharper, I am using `subprocess.PIPE`, shouldn't this forward the terminal standard input to the subprocess? `python` is just an example, there are various other commands that I need to execute that lastly require the stdin.

Comment: No, `subprocess.PIPE` means that you have entirely taken over responsibility for that I/O channel; *nothing* gets into that pipe that you didn't put there yourself.  You may want to try using a module like `pexepect` rather than `subprocess`; this allows any process to be run exactly as if though it was being used interactively, without having to know an equivalent for Python's `-i` parameter for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a pseudo-terminal. Have a look at the [pty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) module.

`pty.fork()` gives you a pid and a file descriptor (the child process gets pid=0). From the parent process you use the file descriptor to read from the terminal and send data to the terminal. Best approach is probably to have a thread reading from the terminal and doing something with the output, such as writing to stdout of the main process.

Here is an example that should accomplish your objective. I've added some additional input to the terminal so that it doesn't hang forever.

```
import pty
import os
import sys
import time
from select import select
import signal
from threading import Thread

class TerminalEmulator:

    def __init__(self, command):
        self.pid = None
        self.fd = None
        self.command = command
        self.thread = None

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.pid is not None:
            raise RuntimerError('Cannot enter multiple times')
        self.pid, self.fd = pty.fork()
        if self.pid:    # Parent
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.communicate)
            self.thread.start()
            return self
        else:           # Child
            os.execlp(*self.command)
            os.exit(1)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        if self.pid:
            try:
                os.waitpid(self.pid, os.WNOHANG)
            except ChildProcessError:
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGHUP)
                    os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
                    # Note: process could still be running after this.
                    # Some better handling would be a good idea.
                except ProcessLookupError:
                    pass
            self.pid = False
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread = None

    def send(self, data):
        os.write(self.fd, data)

    def communicate(self):
        while self.pid:
            rfds, _, _ = select([self.fd], [], [], 1)
            if self.fd in rfds:
                try:
                    data = os.read(self.fd, 10240)
                except OSError:
                    return
                os.write(1, data)

with TerminalEmulator(['bash', '-i']) as terminal:
    terminal.send(b'python3\n')
    terminal.send(b'import time, sys\n')
    terminal.send(b'time.sleep(2)\n')
    terminal.send(b'sys.exit(0)\n')
    terminal.send(b'exit\n')
    os.waitpid(terminal.pid, 0)
```